# What is a good way to hide your cigarette lighter hub?

Tags: interior, power-outlet

Like the title states, what would be the best way do hide/disguise a cigarette lighter hub (image below since i dont know the correct name).

I drive a 2001 seat ibiza 6k2. A friend of mine put it in the feet area of the passenger (shotgun) next to him. I personally dont like this solution but its a viable one none the less.

My question: What would be viable/praktical locations to place a cigarette lighter hub (and still be able to use it).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you're going to be plugging into it - whether you'll be plugging and unplugging stuff regularly, and how long the leads of the things you are using are...

Under the passenger seat could work, as could inside or underneath the glovebox.

When I bought my current car, I found that a previous owner had wired one in behind the fusebox cover (above the driver's footwell, under the steering wheel), then had permanently fitted chargers for a mobile phone and satnav to it. I removed that however as I didn't like the idea of permanently live chargers that I couldn't see!

As you mention, a common place is in the passenger footwell, often screwed or stuck to the side of the centre console - this is more visible but the easiest place to get to regularly... Similarly, you could try (depending on the layout of the car) the back of the centre console - but that may well be too far from where you'd want the leads to go.

Comment: I would mount it on either side of the console (assuming it has one) using sticky backed Velcro adhesive. That stuff can support a ton, then if you don't want it anymore, just remove it with some Goo-Gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, i was considering cutting a small opening in the left side of the passenger footwell and incorporate the hub there. This would however leave me with cables running up the dash when i actually use it. I accepted because of the good ideas.